# Lots of TypeError: fnPtr is not a function in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently extending an angularjs application which was created by someone else and i am running into problems after building it with grunt. Even though the site does work i am getting a lot of `TypeError: fnPtr is not a function` errors in the console. The error stack is not really helpful, but i managed to find two distinct spots inside my application which are named inside those stacks:

1. The first one is a workaround for this bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621. I do believe that this is actually no longer needed (since we are using angular 1.2.6 and as far as i can tell this bug seems to be fixed for this version). Here is the relevant bit:

   ```
   ScopePrototype.$watchCollection = function(obj, listener) {
               var self = this;
               var oldValue;
               var newValue;
               var changeFlipFlop = 0;
               var objGetter = $parse(obj);
               var internalArray = [];
               var internalObject = {};
               var internalLength = 0;

               var internalValue = initWatchVal;

               function $watchCollectionWatch() {
                   var newLength, key, i, changeDetected;

                   newValue = objGetter(self);
                   ....}
   ```

   The error points to: `newValue = objGetter(self);` at some point. Even if i remove this workaround from my code the same spot inside the angular.js file gets named, which does look like this (snippet):

   ```
   $watchCollection: function(obj, listener) {
       var self = this;
       var oldValue;
       var newValue;
       var changeDetected = 0;
       var objGetter = $parse(obj);
       var internalArray = [];
       var internalObject = {};
       var oldLength = 0;

       function $watchCollectionWatch() {
         newValue = objGetter(self);
         var newLength, key;
   ```
2. The second occurrence is even stranger (points to `doCheck`). This is just a simple directive:

   ```
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
           showLeft: '=',
           showRight: '='
       },
       controller: function ($scope) {
           $scope.checkVisibility = function(scrollPosition, elementWidth){
               if(scrollPosition <= 0) {
                   $scope.showLeft = false;
               } else {
                   $scope.showLeft = true;
               }
               if(scrollPosition >= elementWidth) {
                   $scope.showRight = false;
               } else {
                   $scope.showRight = true;
               }

               if(!$scope.$parent.$$phase) { // Prevent digest error
                   $scope.$apply();
               }
           };
       },
   link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
           var doCheck = function(){
               $scope.checkVisibility($element[0].scrollLeft, $element[0].scrollWidth - $element[0].offsetWidth - $attr.rightScrollOffset);

           };

           angular.element($element).scroll(function(){
               doCheck();
           });

           /* use timeout, as $element[0].children[0].offsetWidth is not being ready now */
           $timeout(function(){
               doCheck();
           }, 200);

           /* also set on resize */
           angular.element($window).bind('resize',function(){
               doCheck();
           });

           /* also set on dom node changes of scroll Div */
           angular.element($element).bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
               doCheck();
           });
       }
   ```

All vendor js files are getting "compiled" into one vendor.js file. The strange thing is that it does work without problems when i use an older version of this compiled vendor.js. I already tried to diff both files to see if any versions do mismatch, but i couldn't find anything critical. Anyone any ideas what might happen here? It also happens when i skip the building process and just use each .js file on its own.

Comment: You mention checkVisibility as problematic spot but don't provide the source for it. All the relevant code may be appropriate. Please, provide the error stack (for unminified app when 'each .js file on its own') and let the answerers decide if it is helpful or not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The 2 spots i posted are the only ones outside the angularjs file. What else should I add?

Comment: Ah i see now. Will post once iam back

Comment: @estus i've added the checkVisibility method. I think the problem might start at $scope.apply();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. After a lot of diff action through both files i noticed a mismatch between the angular-bootstrap-tpls libraries. The older vendor.js file used version 0.10.0 and i used 0.11.2.
It is quite strange, because bower wouldn't let me install the version 0.10.0 even though the bower.json file required `angular-bootstrap: "~0.10.0"`. Also version `0.11.2` should be compatible with angular version `1.2.6` (which i am using).